# unsigned int overflow error in converting image to MNIST format

Tags: tensorflow, data-conversion, mnist

I'm a newbie of deep learning utilizing tensorflow. 
I want to make the own model that predict my custom images that are constructed on the grayscale. 
But the only thing that I know is MNIST example utilizing tensorflow.

So I used a converting module from [this repo](https://github.com/gskielian/JPG-PNG-to-MNIST-NN-Format) but the error had been occurred such as this.

[image]

Images like to convert was constructed as 80,680 of training images, 20,170 of test images.

I really don't know why this error has occurred. 
Please help me.

Comment: Could you show more of the error? And are your images scaled to 28x28, grayscale (one channel)?

Comment: I edited the convert file from that repository to work for my own images [here](https://github.com/StanfordAIR/vision-playground/blob/master/gen-img-conv-gzip/converter.py)

Comment: Tried image size is not 28x28, it is 124x124, but these are grayscale.
I will inform the result after executing your script.
I really thank you.

Comment: Your script performs very well! 
I appreciate your kindness and help.

Comment: I'll go ahead and submit it as an answer then. :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you're referring to doesn't correctly set up the headers for the MNIST format. It was addressed in a previous Github issue that has since been deleted, but my [modification](https://github.com/StanfordAIR/vision-playground/blob/master/gen-img-conv-gzip/converter.py):

```
header = array('B')
header.extend([0,0,8,1,0,0])
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[2:][:2],16))
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[2:][2:],16))
```

to

```
header = array('B')
header.extend([0,0,8,1])
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[2:][:2],16))
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[4:][:2],16))
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[6:][:2],16))
header.append(int('0x'+hexval[8:][:2],16))
```

should get it working. Hope this helps!

Comment: It gives me the same problem when I have more than 100 classes. When my class name is greater than or equal to 100, it gives me the same problem. Is there a way to solve? And I am using it for image size of 224*224 grayscale